# Webkit (Safari and Chrome) zero width td with only bottom border is displayed as 1px wide

Tags: css, webkit, html-table, width

My problem is simple to explain but Webkit hard to resolve. Please read below:

I have a **simple table with a single row and two cells** but still the table is displayed **differently in Safari/Chrome than in IE/Firefox**.

The first cell in the single row of the table contains a div which is 150px wide and has a 1px blue border. The second cell in the same row has a red **only bottom** border 25px wide and contains a div which is **0px wide** and has no border.

See the example at http://www.livenetlife.com/Tabletest.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <div style="border: 1px solid blue; width:150px; height:50px;"></div>
                </td>
                <td style="border-left: 0px; border-right:0px; border-top:0px; border-bottom: 25px solid red;">
                    <div style="width:0px; height:0px;"></div>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

**In Firefox and IE the second cell is not displayed** as it is 0 px wide. Test by opening the link above with Firefox or IE and all you will notice is a single blue rectangle (the div in the first cell).

**But in Webkit Browsers (Safari and Chrome) the second cell is displayed too** because it is **mysteriously 1px wide.** Open the link above with Safari or Chrome and you will notice the vertical red line (25px wide bottom border of the second cell) displayed next to the blue rectangle.

**What Webkit CSS am I missing to make the second cell disappear also in Safari and Chrome?**

Any advice would really be appreciated.

PS: Please note that the table above is actually a simplification of the real problem described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660955/100-width-td-in-webkit-browsers-always-at-least-1-pixel-wide). Therefore HTML modification is not possible. Please try to help me find **a (Webkit) CSS solution** for the mentioned problem.

Answer (score 1):

That is definitely a bug in WebKit, seems like known already: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=39381

Use display:none for that cell.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. It really does look like the same bug yes. 

Unfortunately I cannot use display:none, because this design is a simplification of something bigger. It seems now I will need to revert to javascript solution, which is something we wanted to ommit. Thanks again! : )

Answer (score 0):

You can use **display:inline;** in the 2nd **td** of the table. Here is your code with my changes.

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody><tr>
            <td>
                <div style="border: 1px solid blue; width:150px; height:50px;"></div>
            </td>
            <td style="border-left: 0px; border-right:0px; border-top:0px; border-bottom: 25px solid red; display: inline;">
                <div style="width:0px; height:0px;"></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody></table>
```

Comment: Thank you, this definitly solves the problem as it is defined here. However this solution is not good for the origin of this problem as mentioned above (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5660955/100-width-td-in-webkit-browsers-always-at-least-1-pixel-wide)

Answer (score 0):

3+ years later and it looks like this bug still isn't fixed as of Chrome 36.

One way to solve the problem in this particular example is to add a -1px right margin and relative positioning to the div in the first cell, like so:

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div style="position: relative; margin-right: -1px; border: 1px solid blue; width: 150px; height: 50px;"></div>
    </td>
    <td style="border-left: 0px; border-right: 0px; border-top: 0px; border-bottom: 25px solid red;">
      <div style="width: 0px; height: 0px;"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```